# Unable to get Access token in microsoft Oauth 2.0

Tags: azure-active-directory, onenote-api

I am developing the integration for Microsoft One Note with third party application using OAuth 2.0

And I have successfully authorised my Microsoft O365 account and provided my consent, but unable to get access token after the successful authorisation.

Error Message looks like : **Invalid client secret is provided.
                           Timestamp: 2019-03-19 07:52:28Z**

One Note Documentation : [enterprise notebooks on Office 365 integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/how-to/onenote-auth)

Comment: Could you include more details in your question?

Comment: @somasundaram I have updated my answer, you could try this, if you have any more complexity feel free to share.

Answer (score 0):

As the [document states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/how-to/onenote-auth) format should be like below

> ```
> POST https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> grant_type=authorization_code
> &client_id={client-id} // Your Azure portal register application ID
> &client_secret={client-secret} // Key Of same registered application
> &code={code}
> &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
> ```

You are providing invalid client secret key while you are requesting API

See the screen shot below and make sure you are providing right one

[image]

**Note:**

> Check your EXPIRES of key as never expires

**Update:**

In your case you have to follow two step to get your access token

> 1. First need to get authorization  code
> 2. Request for token with that authorization code

**Authorization  code request sample**

[image]

**Token Request sample with authorization code**

[image]

Comment: I have used the below URL for authorisation: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize
  ?response_type=code
  &client_id={client-id}
  &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
  &resource=https://onenote.com/ 
-------------------------------------------------
For Refresh the access token, we used the below URL
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type=authorization_code
&client_id={client-id}
&client_secret={client-secret}
&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
&code={code}
&resource=https://onenote.com/

Comment: And also I have created the client secret as you have shown in the screenshot, Could you please assist me to resolve the issue in better.

Comment: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID: ec685c48-5593-4117-be6e-379bccfdfd00\r\nCorrelation ID: d044101e-fe40-48db-8387-3b41ccf8662e\r\nTimestamp: 2019-03-19 09:23:16Z","error_codes":[7000215],"timestamp":"2019-03-19 09:23:16Z","trace_id":"ec685c48-5593-4117-be6e-379bccfdfd00","correlation_id":"d044101e-fe40-48db-8387-3b41ccf8662e"}

Comment: Could you please look into the issue for the better solution.